# Using Pseudo Color Softcopy Presentation State with Weasis dicom viewer

Tags: python, dicom, pydicom, medical-imaging

I plan to use Pseudo Color Softcopy presentation state(PCSPS) to map pixel values from grayscale space to rgb space. I don't want set the photometric interpretation in the original dicom file to 'Palette color'(it's MONOCHROME2) and add color lut to avoid editing/copying the original file(btw the above method works for getting false color images)

I created a presentation file(*.pre) with the following fields where the reference SOP Instance UID refers to my dicom file. When I load the presentation file into the weasis I can see the effects of changed Modality and VOI but color palette lut is not working, image is still a grayscale image.

```
(0002, 0001) File Meta Information Version       OB: b'\x00\x01'
(0002, 0002) Media Storage SOP Class UID         UI: Pseudo-Color Softcopy Presentation State Storage
(0002, 0003) Media Storage SOP Instance UID      UI: 1.2.826.0.1.3680043.8.498.10772247590204536926265311115669287656
(0002, 0010) Transfer Syntax UID                 UI: Implicit VR Little Endian
(0002, 0012) Implementation Class UID            UI: 1.2.40.0.13.1.4
(0002, 0013) Implementation Version Name         SH: 'graphic_1.0'
-------------------------------------------------
(0008, 0016) SOP Class UID                       UI: Pseudo-Color Softcopy Presentation State Storage
(0008, 0018) SOP Instance UID                    UI: 1.2.826.0.1.3680043.8.498.10772247590204536926265311115669287656
(0008, 0023) Content Date                        DA: '20220602'
(0008, 0033) Content Time                        TM: '195422.999854'
(0008, 0060) Modality                            CS: 'PR'
(0008, 1010) Station Name                        SH: 'DellXPS'
(0008, 103e) Series Description                  LO: 'GSPS'
(0008, 1115)  Referenced Series Sequence  1 item(s) ---- 
   (0008, 1140)  Referenced Image Sequence  1 item(s) ---- 
      (0008, 1150) Referenced SOP Class UID            UI: CT Image Storage
      (0008, 1155) Referenced SOP Instance UID         UI: 1.2.826.0.1.3680043.8.498.14003991661580071171173424711461917486
      ---------
   (0020, 000e) Series Instance UID                 UI: 1.2.826.0.1.3680043.8.498.90028613279640809707933154515673507962
   ---------
(0010, 0010) Patient's Name                      PN: 'Test'
(0010, 0020) Patient ID                          LO: '123'
(0020, 000d) Study Instance UID                  UI: 1.2.826.0.1.3680043.8.498.63124762837262268223850956817440292415
(0020, 000e) Series Instance UID                 UI: 1.2.826.0.1.3680043.8.498.50191488873500476754366946620234552528
(0020, 0010) Study ID                            SH: '1_PR'
(0020, 0011) Series Number                       IS: None
(0020, 0013) Instance Number                     IS: '15'
(0028, 1052) Rescale Intercept                   DS: '5.0'
(0028, 1053) Rescale Slope                       DS: '2.0'
(0028, 1101) Red Palette Color Lookup Table Desc US: [256, 0, 8]
(0028, 1102) Green Palette Color Lookup Table De US: [256, 0, 8]
(0028, 1103) Blue Palette Color Lookup Table Des US: [256, 0, 8]
(0028, 1201) Red Palette Color Lookup Table Data OW: Array of 256 elements
(0028, 1202) Green Palette Color Lookup Table Da OW: Array of 256 elements
(0028, 1203) Blue Palette Color Lookup Table Dat OW: Array of 256 elements
(0028, 2002) Color Space                         CS: 'SRGB'
(0028, 3110)  Softcopy VOI LUT Sequence  1 item(s) ----
   (0028, 1050) Window Center                       DS: '127.0'
   (0028, 1051) Window Width                        DS: '255.0'
   ---------
(0070, 0080) Content Label                       CS: 'PRE_PSEUDO_COLOR'
(0070, 0082) Presentation Creation Date          DA: '20220602'
(0070, 0083) Presentation Creation Time          TM: '195422.999854'
```

My desired output is what we get when the photometric interpretation is set to Palette Color, but I'm not able to get the color image using PCSPS. Can I get the same effect using PCSPS file with the photometric interpretation set to 'Monochrome2' in the reference dicom file?

Comment: Most likely Weasis just doesn't support it - best to ask at [their site](https://github.com/nroduit/Weasis).

Comment: Got to know that they are adding support for the above feature in their next release

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudo Color Sofcopy Presentation state is not supported by weasis as of now. It's expected to be added in their next release by the end of June [ref post](https://groups.google.com/g/dcm4che/c/0j6YGhZvWsk).